# Ckan API to get a list of recently changed datasets(public & private)

Tags: ckan

There is one API to get a list of recently changed datasets in CKAN. But that API returns public datasets. Is there any API in ckan that can return all recently changed datasets that will include public and private datasets?

AVailable API that return recently changed public datasets:
http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/recently_changed_packages_activity_list
for authentication I have used "X-CKAN-API-Key"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for private datasets you will have to query separately per organisation (using the api key)

e.g.
to get the list of organisations:
http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/organization_list

then for each organisation:
http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/organization_show?id=000001

default is that packages are ordered by recent change (unless you've set it up differently)

Comment: `organization_show` returns organization metadata and a list of users, but nothing about datasets or resources (on API v3).

Comment: I've posted an answer to this question [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48886162/1308967)