# How to obtain a given user's dateset list(both public and private) through CKAN API?

Tags: ckan

In my project, I used CKAN to manage my data, now I want to obtain the dataset list under my authorization(both public and private datasets), does anyone know how could I get such a list through CKAN API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get public datasets using `package_list` or `package_search`.

Get datasets that your user has created, including ones that are private and drafts, using `user_show` with option `include_datasets=True`. Remember to use your user's api key, of course.

However I believe this leaves the private datasets created by other members of your organizations, that are not available afaict via the API. I raised an issue: https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/3176 in case you'd like to provide a contribute a fix or bounty for someone else to.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's really what I want. In my opinion, the organization administrator should have privileges to decide whether the members can access all the datasets or only those created by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Now @D Read's [issue](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/3176) has been addressed, this question has a solution:

[`/api/3/action/package_search?include_private=True`](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/#ckan.logic.action.get.package_search)

Using [HTTPie](https://httpie.org/), for example:

```
http https://ckan.example.com/api/3/action/package_search include_private=True Authorization:123-abc
```

Why doesn't

[`/api/3/action/current_package_list_with_resources`](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/#ckan.logic.action.get.current_package_list_with_resources)

get all resources visible to the user with the API key?! If we wanted only public resources we could omit the API key or (most logically to me) filter a search. Anyone else think this should work this way?

Thanks @D Read for the correction.

A further discovery with this endpoint - it returns a maximum of 1000 records, so if you want all results and there may be more than 1000, you need to retrieve in batches. This seems to work - `self.api` is a `ckanapi.RemoteCKAN` instance:

```
ix = 0
results = self.api.action.package_search(
    include_private=True, rows=1000
)
datasets = results["results"]
while len(datasets) < results["count"]:
    ix += 1000
    results = self.api.action.package_search(
        include_private=True, start=ix, rows=1000
    )
    datasets += results["results"]
```

That said, I don't think we ever got this endpoint to work 100% reliably.